# jQuery icheck plugin not working after being append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have ADD button and when I click it append the following:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
       <input type="checkbox"> Sample
    </label>
 </div>
```

to another div (class name .new-option-content). **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lq07ysbq/2/)**

I am using jquery icheck plugin to stylize the check boxes. But when I append I don't see icheck styling on the check boxes. why this can happen ? I call the  function properly but why it's not showing it's styling after append ?

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks

**jQuery**

```
// Radio and Checkboxes

 $('input').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'checkbox-default',
    radioClass: 'radio-default'
  }); 


$('body').on('click', '.add-new-option', function() { 
        $('.new-option-content').append('<div class="checkbox"> <label> <input type="checkbox"> Sample </label> </div>');

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to execute the `isCheck` function again once you append a new item dynamically.
This instruction should be part of the click handler method:

```js
$('body').on('click', '.add-new-option', function() { 
  $('.new-option-content').append('<div class="checkbox"> <label> <input type="checkbox"> Sample </label> </div>');
  $('input').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'checkbox-default',
    radioClass: 'radio-default'
  });
});
```

Here is you [JSFiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/tmarwen/Lq07ysbq/4/).

Comment: Better run plugin on new items only, not all `$('input')`.

Comment: You are welcome, you can mark the answer as accepted if it solved your issue.
Meanwhile you have to take @dfsq note into consideation :)

Answer (score 1):

Just run the check function again for current checkbox. The problem is that you append the checkboxes dynamically.

Js:

```
  // Radio and Checkboxes
 $('input').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'checkbox-default',
    radioClass: 'radio-default'
  }); 


    $('body').on('click', '.add-new-option', function() { 
            $('.new-option-content').append('<div class="checkbox"> <label> <input type="checkbox"> Sample </label> </div>');
        var $lastCheckBox = $('.new-option-content').find('input').last();  
        console.log($lastCheckBox);
          $lastCheckBox.iCheck({
        checkboxClass: 'checkbox-default',
        radioClass: 'radio-default'
      }); 

    });
```

Js fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8w83nue3/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').on('click', '.add-new-option', function() { 
    $('.new-option-content').append('<div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox"> Sample </label></div>');
    $('input').iCheck({
            checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
            radioClass: 'iradio_square-red',
            increaseArea: '20%' 
    });
});
```

Try this one its work fine.

Answer (score -1):

when you append some plugins always try to reintializate the plugins in your JS code, otherwize it will never work.